# React child component rendering before parent component

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs

I have an app setup where I have rails for my backend and react for the front end. I'm using react router to route diff parts of the page. In the App component I'm checking against my backend api for current user based on the JWT token in local storage and setting key of user in state to that user. I'm passing this user as props to the components I want to have limited access based on the existence of a user. This works just fine when I get to that page from links in my NavBar created through react-router, however when I type the url in it will jump to my login page which I've set as the Redirect in my ternary operator where I'm conditionally rendering. Setting up a few console.logs in my App and Dashboard component(child of App) showed that for some reason Dashboard was rendering before App when I refresh the page or try to get to it by directly typing in the page's url. The kickback to the login page happens because Dashboard doesn't have access to the user props yet since App hasn't rendered. I don't know why the child component is rendering before the parent component, but it seems to be the fact that I'm passing in the user props. Any other component where I haven't passed in user props can be refreshed and navigated to through url input. I'm stumped, any input would be appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, doing my best to describe the issue. Basically, when I refresh on a page or go to a page in my react app through typing in the url, the respective page is rendering before my parent component. The child component is relying on the parent component for props. The page will render in the correct order (App first, child component second) if I reach it from a link in my NavBar, otherwise it won't work correctly.

https://imgur.com/a/nzhdxIN
https://imgur.com/a/8IAFWmr
https://imgur.com/a/nKa8sjz